# Android eclipse - Button drawable issue

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button, drawable

first, sorry if my english is not correct, (i'm french) and I've not find the solution for my problem in french websites, so i try here !

In my app, I want to show 7 Buttons with graphisms I created with the GIMP.
So I use, in the XML code for my Buttons (here for my first button) :

```
android:background="@drawable/change_my_button1"
```

-change_my_button1 is an XML  file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" 
      android:state_enabled="false" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/button-1" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/button1-2" />

<item android:state_enabled="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/button1" />
```

If I press the button, its aspect change.
All of that works perfectly with my button1, button2 and button3.

But when I apply this method for my button4, the app crashs and i have a message "Unfortunatly, the application my_app has stoped"

I thought my images "button4" and "button4-2" are wrong but no ! When I delete the code line

```
android:background="@drawable/change_my_button1"
```

from the XML code of my first Button, then the image for my fourth Button works perfectly...
Maybe the res/drawable/ folder may contain only a restrict number of images ?
I've tried to put those two images in several res/drawable/ folders, but it's not working...

I hope you'll understand my problem...

Please help me ! That is a pain in the ass for me...

Thanks !  :)

Comment: Post logs form logcat

Comment: Update your post it will be more clarity

Comment: you mean i should edit my question and add those logcat lines ?

Comment: yes but add complete error stack trace. When you get error on your device it is displayed on logcat  as stack trace. It allows to recognise why this issue occours

Comment: I'm so sorry but there are hundreds of lines since the begin of the thread...  I have to copy only the red lines ?

Comment: Do you use Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: thanks for your patience anyway

Comment: I use the android SDK on eclipse

Comment: welcome :) I want to help you

Comment: so clear your logcat set filter as error and run you application with connected device. When you can see "Unfortunately... " dialog on your logcat will be displayed error it is what interesting me

Comment: I tried to copy all red lines which appears in the same time that the message, but there are 8100 characters... I don't know what to do i'm sorry

Comment: I need only sth like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/GluOw.png

Comment: https://imageshack.com/i/ey2FmOkdj

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resources are to big and you get `OutOfMemoryError`. You have to scale your resources for screen resolution which you support. I mean **xxhdpi** **xhdpi** **hdpi** etc. Probably all your resources are in drawable folder. It is wrong. They should be in **drawable-xxhdpi**, **drawable-xhdpi**, etc folders with proper size with proportions:

```
hdpi = mdpi * 1.5
xhdpi = mdpi * 2
xxhdpi = mdpi *3
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to adapt my images for all supports, isn't it ? Should-I do that from the code or i have to make several images with different size from photoshop or gimp ?

Comment: My resources are too big mean that i have too much images in my res/drawable folder or my images are too heavy ?

Comment: You should create drawable folder for all screen resolution which you want to support and scale your images as is described above. It can be in gimp or photoshop

Comment: Ok I'll do that and I'll tell you if it works but when i have an image, how can i know if it's a mdpi image/hdpi,etc...

Comment: You have to create 4 folders drawable-xxhdpi drawable-xhdpi drawable-hdpi drawable-mdpi if you add some drawable to one folder you have to add drawable with the same name to other but on proper size, your device has specified which drawable it should use

Comment: I tried only for my fourth button, and it still not work, I will do that for all my butons now

Comment: I found that on a website : ldpi = 120dpi (or ppi, the same)     mdpi = 160    hdpi = 240     xhdpi = 360     xxhdpi = 480          it is correct ?

Comment: Basically the most important are proportions and size look on your values and my comparisons...

Comment: What is the size of drawable of your button?

Comment: my buttons size :   X : 720px         Y : 300px

Comment: I changed only the resolution but i let unchanged the size in all my drawable folders, maybe i should change the size with your proportions, that's it ?    And again, thanks for your help and patience :)

Comment: Yes. Your button are to big for mdpi and hdpi and xxhdpi resolutions For example when you have size 300px in xxhdpi you have to set 200px in xhdpi 150px in hdpi 100px in mdpi.

Comment: Ok, I changed the size with your proportions and the resolution with that i found and written just above but it still not work... I have to do that with all my project's drawable, maybe ?

Comment: Yes for all drawables which you use

Comment: Ok, it will take a while because my project use about 20-30 drawable...  I'll inform you ;)

Comment: Yeaaaah perfect ! I didn't finish for all of my drawable yet, but i changed half of them and my app don't crash anymore ! Thank you very much ! You help me with something which bother me since a while ! I'll finish my app and I'll tell you if all of that works perfectly !

Comment: I hope someday I could help you in return but i have to progress ;)

Comment: I glad that I could help you :)